# How to pass an array of strings in string literal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, highcharts, ecmascript-6

I have a json object in string literal

```
chartOptionsStr = `{
    "chart": {
      "type": "line"
    },
    "title": {
      "text": ""
    },
    "subtitle": {
      "text": ""
    },
    "xAxis": {
      "categories": ${categories},
      "labels": {
        "align":"right",
        "rotation":"0"
    }
    },
    "yAxis": {
      "title": {
        "text": "Number of Messages"
      },
    "tickInterval": 5
    },
    "plotOptions": {
      "line": {
        "dataLabels": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "enableMouseTracking": true
      }
    },
    "series": [{
      "name": "Sent",
      "data": [37.0, 26.9, 30.5, 47.5]
    }, {
      "name": "Delivered",
      "data": [27.0, 16.9, 20.5, 37.5]
    }, {
      "name": "Open",
      "data": [27.0, 16.9, 20.5, 37.5]
    }]
  }`;
```

In this object I need to pass an array categories

```
["19.Dec","12.Jan","15.Feb","28 Mar"]  as a dynamic value using ${categories}
```

But the problem is when I console this **chartOptionsStr** its showing below output:

```
{
    "chart": {
      "type": "line"
    },
    "title": {
      "text": ""
    },
    "subtitle": {
      "text": ""
    },
    "xAxis": {
      "categories": 12.Dec,18.Dec,20.Dec,1.Jan,
      "labels": {
        "align":"right",
        "rotation":"0"
    }
    },
    "yAxis": {
      "title": {
        "text": "Number of Messages"
      },
    "tickInterval": 5
    },
    "plotOptions": {
      "line": {
        "dataLabels": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "enableMouseTracking": true
      }
    },
    "series": [{
      "name": "Sent",
      "data": [37.0, 26.9, 30.5, 47.5]
    }, {
      "name": "Delivered",
      "data": [27.0, 16.9, 20.5, 37.5]
    }, {
      "name": "Open",
      "data": [27.0, 16.9, 20.5, 37.5]
    }]
  }
```

The array of strings getting appended as a single value.

Does any body have solution for this?

I am trying to fetch the categories of highcharts from angular service. So this value is dynamic.

Comment: convert string to object using JSON.parse and assign categories. If you want again you can convert to string format using JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 1):

Why are you making the JSON a string?

You should create the JSON as a normal object;

```
chartOptionsJson = {
  "chart": {
    "type": "line"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": categories,
    "labels": {
      "align":"right",
      "rotation":"0"
  }
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Number of Messages"
    },
  "tickInterval": 5
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "line": {
      "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "enableMouseTracking": true
    }
  },
  "series": [{
    "name": "Sent",
    "data": [37.0, 26.9, 30.5, 47.5]
  }, {
    "name": "Delivered",
    "data": [27.0, 16.9, 20.5, 37.5]
  }, {
    "name": "Open",
    "data": [27.0, 16.9, 20.5, 37.5]
  }]
};
```

Then you don't need to wrap the categories variable as `${categories}` when injecting into the array, instead just pass the variable directly into the object.

Comment: As I mentioned I am using angular service to fetch ${categories}, if I assign this.categories its resulting undefined. So I am using string literal inside subscribe call and assigning the service data , before i parse the string using JSON.parse(chartOptionsJson);

Comment: See my answer. `categories` is defined, you don't need to call `this.categories`. You don't need to make it a string first, you can just pass the variable as in my example above.

Comment: @MuraliKrishna If you insist on a JSON string, then you should still use the object literal and just use `JSON.stringify` on it.

Answer (score -2):

If you decide to implement this behaviour, you can use:

```
const categoriesStr = `["${categories.join('", "')}"]`;
...
"xAxis": {
  "categories": ${categoriesStr},
   ...
}
```